# How can I right-aligned my Button Component in ModalHeader Component in React JS

Tags: css, arrays, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I want my React Button Component (imported from reactstrap) to get right-aligned in my Modal

```html
<ModalHeader style={{ display: 'flex'}}>
    Start Chatting
    <Button 
      className="nav-btn" 
      size="sm" 
      style={{ marginLeft: '20px',}}>
      <i 
        className="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg" 
        style={{ marginRight: '5px'}}>
      </i>Create Room
    </Button>
    <Button 
      className="end-chat" 
      color="danger" 
      size="sm" 
      style={{ float: 'right'}}>
      <i className="fa fa-sign-out fa-lg">
      </i>End Chat
    </Button>
</ModalHeader>
```

Header Component (also imported from reactstrap). Kindly help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Try using `pushd D:` instead

Comment: Thank You. It did work but why is cd command not working?

Comment: `cd` only work if you try to navigate within the same volume. You can use cd by running `D:` and then `cd Folder1/Subfolder1`

Comment: `cd /D D:\ `is the solution when you want to change to the root of drive `D:`. `cd D:\ `switches the current directory of drive `D:` to its root. Note that every drive has got its own current directory...

Answer (score -1):

Use the command `CD /?` and read about the `/D` switch.

```
CD /D D:\
```